# Align Text to the bottom of a line with an image in HTML

Tags: html, css, css-position

Hi i have HTML with an Inline-Image  like this

```
<p style="">
    <img src="df9b4006-930e-45d7-8123-bec019a37800.png" height="178" width="112">text
</p>
```

but the text is vertical-centered  to the image, how can i position it on the bottom-base-line of the image in the same line?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
p img {vertical-align: baseline;}
```

And here is info about vertical-align: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: As the doc you pointed to indicates, `baseline` is the default. Wonder why it's being set to `middle` for OP.

Comment: He probably had some other style set somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `vertical-align` and `text-bottom` for your example:

```
p img {
   vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/pSKYm/2/

Comment: where is the difference to andi's solution?